# Pivoting pandas with removal of some headers and renaming of some indexes

Tags: python, pandas, pivot

I have the following pandas dataframe:

```
    count  event      date
0    1544  'strike'   2016-11-01
1     226  'defense'  2016-11-01
2    1524  'strike'   2016-12-01
3     246  'defense'  2016-12-01
4    1592  'strike'   2017-01-01
5     245  'defense'  2017-01-01
```

I want to pivot/transform it in such a way the final output looks like this:

```
event     2016-11-01 2016-12-01 2017-01-01 2017-02-01 2017-03-01                                                                     
'strike'        1544       1524       1592       1608       1654   
'defense'        226        246        245        210        254
```

but what i'm getting now upon pivoting is this:

```
                        count          count            count           count             count\
date          2016-11-01 2016-12-01 2017-01-01 2017-02-01 2017-03-01   
event                                                                  
'strike'            1544       1524       1592       1608       1654   
'defense'            226        246        245        210        254
```

is there any way i could remove the entire empty row ahead of the `event` index-name and rename the `date` index-name with `event` as its index-name and also remove the unwanted `count` appearing in the first row of the data frame? The data seems to be transforming correctly i just want to get rid of these headers and indexes and have the renamed and removed properly. I also don't want the row labels in the desired output.

This is what i've been trying till now:

```
output = df.pivot(index='event', columns='date')
print(output)
```

Comment: What is your code for `pivot` ?

Comment: @jezrael my bad, forgot to add the code. editted now

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solution is add parameter `values` to [`pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html), then add [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) for column from `index` and [`rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html) fro remove column name:

```
output=df.pivot(index='event',columns='date',values='count').reset_index().rename_axis(None,1)
print(output)
       event  2016-11-01  2016-12-01  2017-01-01
0  'defense'         226         246         245
1   'strike'        1544        1524        1592
```

What happens if omit it?

```
print (df)
   count      event        date  count1
0   1544   'strike'  2016-11-01       1
1    226  'defense'  2016-11-01       7
2   1524   'strike'  2016-12-01       8
3    246  'defense'  2016-12-01       3
4   1592   'strike'  2017-01-01       0
5    245  'defense'  2017-01-01       1
```

`pivot` use each not used column and create `MultiIndex` for distinguish original columns:

```
output = df.pivot(index='event', columns='date')
print(output)
               count                           count1                      
date      2016-11-01 2016-12-01 2017-01-01 2016-11-01 2016-12-01 2017-01-01
event                                                                      
'defense'        226        246        245          7          3          1
'strike'        1544       1524       1592          1          8          0
```

Comment: @AmanSingh - Yes, you are right, `pivot_table` aggregate. But if need remove `0,1` and use `output=df.pivot(index='event',columns='date',values='count').reset_index().rename_axis(None,1)`  with `output.to_csv(file, index=False)` all working perfectly.

Comment: Used this approach today and it worked perfectly, 2 years later :)

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend using the more general version of `pd.pivot()`, which is `pd.pivot_table()`, like so:

```
x = pd.pivot_table(df, index = 'event', columns = 'date', values = 'count')
```

You will get:

```
date    01/01/2017  01/11/2016  01/12/2016
event           
'defense'   245         226        246
'strike'    1592        1544       1524
```

Next, you can get rid of the 'date' string by setting:

```
x.columns.name = ' '
```

Additionally, if you want to change the order of the events, you might want to set the variable up as a categorical variable, before doing the pivoting:

```
df.event = df.event.astype('category') # cast to categorical
df.event.cat.set_categories(your_list, inplace = True) # force order
```

where `your_list` is the list of your categories, in order.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I dislike this solution a lot, because if use `pivot` and get duplicates, it know, because error. But if use `pivot_table` it always aggregate. So no idea about dupes. So it is better only if need aggregate, else not. Also it is slowier as `pivot`.