# Python Pandas - Matrix Generation From CSV

Tags: python, pandas, csv

Beginner to Pandas, but i *think* it is the right tool for this.

I have a CSV file that looks like this, showing the relationship between Source/Destination/Value:

| Source | Destination | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Item1 | Item1 | true |
| Item1 | Item2 | true |
| Item2 | Item1 | false |
| Item2 | Item2 | true |

(there are thousands of "items")

The end goal is to achieve a CSV such as:

|  | Item1 | Item2 | Item3 | Item4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Item1 | true | true | false | false |
| Item2 | true | false | true | true |

I have generated a new CSV with the Row Headers and Column Headers, however, i am not sure how to fill in the value element.
How can i read in the CSV to maintain the relationship between Source/Dest/Value and output to a CSV?
Current code that generates a new CSV:

```py
df = pd.read_csv('Input.csv')
unique = df['Source'].unique()
unique.sort()
headers = [x for x in unique]
outfile = open("newcsv.csv",'w+', newline='')
writer = csv.writer(outfile,delimiter = ',', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
writer.writerow([" "] + headers)
for item in headers:
    writer.writerow([item])
```

Comment: where does item3 and item4 come from in your desired output ?

Comment: Shouldn't the output be `Item2  false true` ?

Comment: Not sure about item3 and item4 but other than that you could:  `df.pivot(index='Source', columns='Destination', values='Value') `

Comment: The example outputs were just example data to make it easier to show the intention. I didnt double check the dummy data between the examples! The real data is 3000 lines long! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few options for you. You can go with `pivot` (an example is already in the comments) or `pivot_table`. The difference of them is that `pivot_table` can handle duplicate values of a pivoted column, so if you do have rows where the same relationship is shown again, go with that.

Code can look like that:

```
df = pd.read_csv('Input.csv')

res = df.pivot_table(values='Value', index='Source', columns='Destination',aggfunc=max)
# without aggfunc, you get 0 and 1 as result, you can also go with "any" for example. 
# if duplicate rows with different value in "Value" then you can decide about how these values gets aggregated.

res.to_csv('Output.csv')
```

Other possibility would be `pd.crosstab` (you'd also have to choose an aggfunc here) or

Comment: Many thanks. The Pivot_Table method works nearly perfectly. My first row is just my Source column name repeated however, but a quick Google around this has thrown up a couple of solutions to test out!

Comment: you mean your first row in the input.csv isn't the header? by default read_csv assumes that the first row are the column names of the file. if not you have to add `header=None`. I'd change it to make it a valid answer.

Comment: No the first row of "inputs" is the header. Running into the same issue as this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49405336/pivoting-pandas-with-removal-of-some-headers-and-renaming-of-some-indexes - Cant seem to remove that repeated header top row, the "count   count   count" in that example case on the link

Comment: okay. I guess I couldn't know since we only looked at the example data. Glad you solved it and I could help!

Comment: Appreciate the help Rabinzel. Ill try and figure out how to remove the offending lines! :)

Answer (score 1):

I think pandas 'pivot' would help you here.

```
df = pd.read_csv("./source-def.csv", sep="\t")
df_op = df.pivot(index='Source', columns='Destination', values='Value').fillna(False)

df_op.head()
```

| Destination | Item1 | Item2 | Item3 | Item4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Source |  |  |  |  |
| Item1 | True | True | False | False |
| Item2 | False | True | True | True |

Finally, you can use 'to_csv' like this to write the file into another CSV file again.

```
df_op.to_csv('pivot.csv')
```

Comment: With `pivot` i get this error: `    "Shape of passed values is {0}, indices imply {1}".format(passed, implied)
ValueError: Shape of passed values is (3136, 1), indices imply (1, 1)`

Comment: @Dr.Pepper I am not sure what is causing this but could please try with `pd.crosstab(df['Source'], df['Destination'])` or `pd.crosstab(df['Source'], df['Destination'], df['Value'], aggfunc=max)`. If possible can you please share some sample data.

Comment: Thanks Deep_learner - `crosstab` seems to have done the trick :). The `Source` column name appears in cell A1, rather than being blank, but i can manually delete that! Appreciate it